# Jquery code not removing TR from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I wrote a bit of code to remove a table row if the checkbox within that row is checked. I'm trying to get this to work as shown below but I'm having trouble targetting the TR itself. Can someone give me a pointer as to what I'm doing wrong? Or maybe I'm approaching this in the least efficient way?

```
$(".deleter").click( function() {
        $(".table1 td :checked").prop("checked") ? $(".row1")remove() : $(".msgbox").text("There is nothing to delete.");
    });

<div class="table1"><form>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Primary</th>

                <th>Address</th>

                <th>Construction</th>

                <th>Town Grade</th>

                <th>Select All<br /><input type="checkbox" class="selectall" name="specialtable"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row1">
                <td><input type="radio" name="primary_loc" /></td>

                <td>#501 - 2206 Eglinton Avenue, Scarborough, O.N. A1B2C3</td>

                <td>Fire Resistive</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td><input type="checkbox" name="specialtable"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row2">
                <td><input type="radio" name="primary_loc" /></td>

                <td>#501 - 2206 Eglinton Avenue, Scarborough, O.N. A1B2C3</td>

                <td>Fire Resistive</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td><input type="checkbox" name="specialtable"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: First off, your code `$(".row1")remove()` is invalid JavaScript and will cause the script to abort.

Comment: Are you absolutely *sure* the JavaScript console isn't telling you about a syntax error?

Comment: Why didn't you check console if things are not working properly? Such type of questions should not be asked here as these can be fixed by checking `console`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is just to remove a row as soon as its checkbox gets clicked, then the following snippet accomplishes that.

Note that your checkboxes didn't have the `deleter` class; I added that.

```js
$('.deleter').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table1">
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Primary</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Construction</th>
                <th>Town Grade</th>
                <th>Select All
                    <br />
                    <input type="checkbox" class="selectall" name="specialtable" />
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row1">
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="primary_loc" />
                </td>
                <td>#501 - 2206 Eglinton Avenue, Scarborough, O.N. A1B2C3</td>
                <td>Fire Resistive</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="specialtable" class="deleter" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row2">
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="primary_loc" />
                </td>
                <td>#501 - 2206 Eglinton Avenue, Scarborough, O.N. A1B2C3</td>
                <td>Fire Resistive</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="specialtable" class="deleter" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".row1").remove()
```

You will need to use .remove() instead of just remove().

Answer (score 0):

You do need a `.deleter` element a `.msgbox` element. You can use `:checked` psedo selector together with `.length` to check whether any `checkbox` is checked; delete the row if there is, otherwise output message.

```js
$(".deleter").click(function() {
  $('.msgbox').empty();
  $(".table1 td :checked").length ? 
    $(".table1 td :checked").closest('tr').remove() : 
  $(".msgbox").text("There is nothing to delete.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="table1">
  <form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Primary</th>

        <th>Address</th>

        <th>Construction</th>

        <th>Town Grade</th>

        <th>Select All
          <br />
          <input type="checkbox" class="selectall" name="specialtable">
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row1">
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="primary_loc" />
        </td>

        <td>#501 - 2206 Eglinton Avenue, Scarborough, O.N. A1B2C3</td>

        <td>Fire Resistive</td>

        <td>2</td>

        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="specialtable">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2">
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="primary_loc" />
        </td>

        <td>#501 - 2206 Eglinton Avenue, Scarborough, O.N. A1B2C3</td>

        <td>Fire Resistive</td>

        <td>2</td>

        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="specialtable">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
<button class="deleter">Delete</button>
<div class="msgbox"></button>
```